# How to save a generated QR code to Google Photo App?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, qr-code

I have created a QR Code Generator App and it works very well. So, I wanted to let the user save, their generated QR code, to either the Google Photo App or a different one, that the user has downloaded.

I have been working on this for a couple of hours now, and couldn't find my answer via the internet.

Here is the code I have tried, and still have:

```
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    SAVEbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SAVE);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditTextValue = editText.getText().toString();

            try {
                bitmap = TextToImageEncode(EditTextValue);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (WriterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    //Here is the code I have been working with....

    SAVEbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

            //  Get path to new gallery image
            Uri path = context.getContentResolver ().insert (MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
            try
            {
                OutputStream stream = context.getContentResolver ().openOutputStream (path);
                bitmap.compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.e (TAG, "E: " + e.getMessage ());
            }
        }


    });



}
```

I had hoped that, with the above code, I could save the generated QR code to photo gallery apps (including the google photo app). But, the `context` and `TAG` are highlighted in red.

Comment: If there is a better way to save a QR code to an image gallery, please don't hesitate to tell me!

Comment: Context could be the the activity you are running. If it is MainActivity then `Uri path = context.getContentResolver ()` would be `MainActivity.this..getContentResolver ().` and `TAG` should be a `private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();` If you have that in red I guess you haven't been able to run this code yet right? Have you taken care of permissions for the External folder? And also why use Audio for Images?

Comment: Thanks very much! I changed the lines of code your mentioned, and ran it.....But, when I click Save Image it takes me to the home screen of the device. Also, this is the first time I have ever saved an Image to an Android Device's photo gallery, so I was trying to piece together the right code to use. Which, apparently, isn't working for me.